# Access same object value in another location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, object-oriented-analysis

I have a simple C# login system (Winform application). I have a separated class (`ActiveUser`) to store user details when they're logging in.

In `ActiveUser` class, I have a variable called `loggedInUserID`.

So, when the user logs in, on the login form, I set a value to that variable.

```
ActiveUser obj = new ActiveUser();
obj.setLoggedUserID(UserID);
```

Now I have a `CheckLoggedIn()` method in each form that checks whether the user is logged in or not. So, that I can block users from accessing unauthorized pages.

So, how to check that ?  If I did like this, it's just another object.

```
CheckLoggedIn(){

    ActiveUser obj = new ActiveUser();

    if(obj.getLoggedUserID() != 0){
        MessageBox.Show("Logged In");
    }
}
```

So, how to check the object value I create when the user logging in ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the *Singleton Pattern* is the most suitable in this situation.

Let's make `ActiveUser` a simple singleton class.

In the `ActiveUser` class, add something like this:

```
public static readonly ActiveUser User = new ActiveUser();
```

To `SetLoggedUserID`, just do:

```
ActiveUser.User.SetLoggedUser(...);
```

And you can check it like this:

```
void CheckLoggedIn(){

    if(ActiveUser.User.getLoggedUserID() != 0){
        MessageBox.Show("Logged In");
    }
}
```

To avoid accidentally creating a new instance of `ActiveUser`, I recommend you to make the constructor private:

```
private ActiveUser() { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to set an integer value to `User` variable ? It says "Cannot implicitly convert..."

Comment: @TharinduLucky You seem to come from a js background. Unfortunately, you can't set anything other than `ActiveUser` instances to `User`. C# uses mostly static typing. And it is not suitable to use the `dynamic` keyword here. What are you trying to do? I smell an XY problem.

Comment: yeah I know little bit JS. What I'm trying to do is, in the logging page, I need to set users `ID` to the `User ` variable in the ActiveUser class. Since the class can be accessed anywhere in the program I can check if the user has logged in or not

Comment: @TharinduLucky I don't know what you're talking about, but you can just set user's ID the same way you did before: `obj.setLoggedUserID(UserID);` except you change `obj` to `ActiveUser.User`. If the code you've shown compiles successfully, then so should `ActiveUser.User.setLoggedUserID(UserID);`

Comment: So, if I set the value like this, `obj.setLoggedUserID(UserID);`, how to access that value in another form ?

Comment: You should use `ActiveUser.User` instead of `obj` @TharinduLucky
if you want to access the value in another form, do `ActiveUser.User.getLoggedUserID()`. Did you even read my answer?

Comment: Thanks!, I did exactly as you instructed. But, unable to set the value. Would u like this to move to a chat ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120848/discussion-between-sweeper-and-tharindulucky).